# Html table size column

Tags: html, html-table

I have a table but I don't know how to have control on the size of the first column. I would like the first column is 65% seconde 35

```html
<table width=""193""  cellspacing=""0"" cellpadding=""0"">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td valign=""top""><strong>Nutrition facts:</strong></td>
<td valign=""top""><strong>100ml</strong></td>
</tr><tr>"&"
<td valign=""top""><strong>Calories:</strong></td>
<td valign=""top"">"3g"</td>
</tr>"&"<tr>
<td valign=""top""><strong>Carbohydrate:</strong></td>
<td valign=""top"">"5g"</td>
</tr>"&"
<tr>
<td valign=""top"">sugar:</td>
<td valign=""top"">"4g"</td>
</tr>"&"
<tr>
<td valign=""top""><strong>Sodium:</strong></td>
<td valign=""top"">"2g"</td>
</tr></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: kindly accept answer and upvote if the answer suits the purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Table width should be 100%. Then you can make the table headers 65% and 35%. Hope this helps.

```html
<table style="width:100%; text-align: center;" >
  <tr>
    <th style="width:65%"><strong>Nutrition facts:</strong></th>
    <th style="width:35%"><strong>100ml</strong></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="" top""><strong>Calories:</strong></td>
    <td valign="" top"">"3g"</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="" top""><strong>Carbohydrate:</strong></td>
    <td valign="" top"">"5g"</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="" top""><strong>Sugar:</strong></td>
    <td valign="" top"">"4g"</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign=""top""><strong>Sodium:</strong></td>
    <td valign=""top"">"2g"</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```